# Property not recognized in Coldfusion ORM Persistent entity

Tags: sql-server, orm, coldfusion

I have a persistent ORM entity:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" table="MENU_recipeTypes" entityname="recipeTypes" >
    <cfproperty name="id" fieldtype="id" column="recipeType_id" generator="native" setter="false">
    <cfproperty name="name" column="recipeType_name" type="string">
    <cfproperty name="recipeType_help" column="recipeType_help" type="string">
    <cfproperty name="hasPrice" column="hasPrice" type="binary">
    <cfproperty name="recipeTypeOrder" type="numeric">
    <cfproperty name="exclusiveType" type="binary">
    <cfproperty name="recipe" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="recipes" fkcolumn="recipeType_id" type="array">
    <cfproperty name="recipeTypeDisplay" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="recipeTypeDisplay" fkcolumn="recipeType_id" type="array">
</cfcomponent>
```

On my local machine running Windows 10 and SQL Express 2017 with CF2018 everything runs smoothly. However, on the server running Windows Server 2019 Datacenter with SQL Express 2019 and CF2021, the property 'hasPrice' can not be found for some reason.

I am at a complete loss why this is happening.

Testing it out:

```
<cfset thisRecipeType = entityLoadByPK("recipeTypes", 5)>
<cfdump var="#thisRecipeType#">
```

Result:

[image: Dump result]

Data in the database:

[image]

So the hasPrice column for entity 5 clearly has a value in it.

ADDENDUM: It appears that MSSQL2017 accepts the type 'bit' or 'binary' as a valid type for boolean values but MSSQL2019 does not accept either and only accepts boolean. This does not cause an error but rather returns 'undefined value'.

Comment: Strictly a guess, but `type="binary"` looks odd.  Try `type="boolean"` and see what happens.

Comment: Brilliant, that's it! Thank you. I can't mark this as the answer though. If you want post this as the answer and I will mark as the answer. Not sure why I didn't come up with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the hasPrice property has `type="binary"`.  In ColdFusion, true/false properties should have `type="boolean"`